# Dilemma: Renaming a spark database

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I am working with a team to build a spark datawarehouse/data platform. The approved architecture suggests that the databases are created on the fly with data from persisted parquet files. The parquet files are made up to date with current and historical data.

The data is then loaded to a landing, staging and presentation layers (built in Apache Spark pool in Azure Synapse) using Azure Synapse pipelines. These layers, as per the architecture, are not persisted. They are dropped and recreated every night.

Since I did not want the users to impacted with a failure I was looking at options to load the data into new databases every night, drop the old databases and then rename the newly created databases. This will ensure that the business users will have access to data at all times.

Question:
Is there anyway to rename spark databases in Azure Synapse?

NB: Not sure if this question is to be asked in this format, but any comments/suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you check if this works: `spark.sql(RENAME DATABASE <old_db_name> to <new_db_name>)`

Comment: There is no "RENAME DATABASE" but you can change database location using `ALTER DATABASE <database-name> SET LOCATION <new-location>` which might be what you need. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-database.html#alter-location

Comment: @SaideepArikontham Thank you for that. I do understand TSQL, but not sure if I could use it to rename a Spark database.

Comment: @mazaneicha .. Thank you. I might try changing the location and see what happens.